# Fortran array of variable size arrays

Tags: multidimensional-array, fortran

A simplified description of the problem:

There are exactly *maxSize* people shopping in a store. Each of them has a shopping list, containing the price of items (as integers). Using Fortran arrays, how can I represent all the shopping lists. The shopping lists may contain *any* number of items (1, 10, 1000000000).

(NOTE: The actual problem is far more complicated. It is not even about shopping.)

The lazy approach would be:

```
integer :: array(maxSize, A_REALLY_BIG_NUMBER)
```

However, this is very wasteful, I basically want the second dimension to be variable, and then allocate it for each person seperately.

The obvious attempt, doomed to failure:

```
integer, allocatable :: array(:,:)
allocate(array(maxSize, :)) ! Compiler error
```

Fortran seems to require that arrays have a fixed size in each dimension.

This is wierd, since most languages treat a multidimensional array as an "array of arrays", so you can set the size of each array in the "array of arrays" seperately.

Here is something that *does* work:

```
type array1D
    integer, allocatable :: elements(:) ! The compiler is fine with this!
endtype array1D

type(array1D) :: array2D(10)
integer :: i

do i=1, size(array2D)
    allocate(array2D(i)%elements(sizeAt(i))
enddo
```

If this is the only solution, I guess I will use it. But I was kind of hoping there would be a way to do this using intrinsic functions. Having to define a custom type for such a simple thing is a bit annoying.

In C, since an array is basically a pointer with fancy syntax, you can do this with an array of pointers:

```
int sizeAt(int x); //Function that gets the size in the 2nd dimension
int * array[maxSize];

for (int x = 0; x < maxSize; ++x)
        array[x] = (int*)(calloc(sizeAt(x) , sizeof(int)));
```

Fortran seems to have pointers too. But the only tutorials I have found all say "NEVER USE THESE EVER" or something similar.

Comment: This is a rant, not a question.

Comment: This is a standard solution in Fortran to what you want to do.   There is nothing wrong with it.   There is nothing wrong with Fortran pointers.  I use them for data structures such as linked lists.  I recommend not using pointers if allocatables will work.  Don't expect Fortran and C to be the same.

Comment: I certainly didn't mean to offend everyone by posting C code!
I was just curious as to whether there was a better way to do it in Fortran, possibly similar to the C solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be complaining that Fortran isn't C.  That's true.  There are probably a near infinite number of reasons why the standards committees chose to do things differently, but here are some thoughts:

One of the powerful things about fortran arrays is that they can be sliced.

```
a(:,:,3) = b(:,:,3)
```

is a perfectly valid statement.  *This could not be achieved if arrays were "arrays of pointers to arrays"* since the dimensions along each axis would not necessarily be consistent (the very case you're trying to implement).

In C, there really is no such thing as a multidimensional array.  You can implement something that looks similar using arrays of pointers to arrays, but that isn't really a multidimensional array since it doesn't share a common block of memory.  This can have performance implications.  In fact, in HPC (where many Fortran users spend their time), a multi-dimensional C array is often a 1D array wrapped in a macro to calculate the stride based on the size of the dimensions.  Also, dereferencing a 7D array like this:

```
a[i][j][k][l][m][n][o]
```

is a good bit more difficult to type than:

```
a(i,j,k,l,m,n,o)
```

Finally, the solution that you've posted is closest to the C code that you're trying to emulate -- what's wrong with it?  Note that for your problem statement, a more complex data-structure (like a linked-list) might be in order (which can be implemented in C or Fortran).  Of course, linked-lists are the worst as far as performance goes, but if that's not a concern, it's probably the correct data structure to use as a "shopper" can decide to add more things into their "cart", even if it wasn't on the shopping list they took to the store.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I can't vote for it. Thanks.

Comment: You as a question poster are not supposed to vote but to accept or not accept a question. Others would or would no vote for this answer (but the question is closed).