# fortran "array of arrays" and "pack" issues

Tags: fortran

I seem to have hit a wall while coding these past few days. from what i can gather, it is possible to make arrays of arrays in fortran ala [Fortran array of variable size arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959386/fortran-array-of-variable-size-arrays)

```
type par
  .... !data 
  integer :: location
end type par

type locations
  ....! data
  type (par), allocatable, dimension(:) :: pars
end type locations

type (par), allocatable, dimension(:) :: all_pars
type (locations), allocatable, dimension(:) :: all_loc

.... !read numpars, numlocs from file etc

allocate(all_pars(numpars))
allocate(all_locs(numlocs))


!initialize all_pars
do n = 1:numpars
  ....
  all_pars(n)%location = some_location
enddo

!get particles in each location 
do n = 1:numlocs
  allocate(all_locs(n)%pars(count(all_pars(:)%location .ne. n)))
  all_locs(n)%pars = pack(all_pars, (all_pars(:)%location .ne. n)) !ERROR: An assignment of different structure types is invalid.
enddo
```

the compiler does not complain with my equivalent lines of code for the stack overflow example above, but it indeed does have an issue when i attempt to use that array to store the result of a pack function call. i suspect that it may be the case that the allocate function is not behaving as expected, but since the code does not compile, i cannot debug it....

the squirrely idea for pack usage comes from http://flibs.sourceforge.net/fortran_aspects.html , about halfway down the page.

I am running on a linux system, with ifort 12.1.3.293

any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be an extended comment rather than an answer ...

to get it to compile I modified your posted code to;

```
program main

implicit none

integer :: numpars, numlocs, n

type par
  !data
  integer :: location
end type par

type locations
  ! data
  type (par), allocatable, dimension(:) :: pars
end type locations

type (par), allocatable, dimension(:) :: all_pars
type (locations), allocatable, dimension(:) :: all_locs

!read numpars, numlocs from file etc
numpars = 10
numlocs = 4
allocate(all_pars(numpars))
allocate(all_locs(numlocs))


!initialize all_pars
all_pars(1:numpars:4)%location = 1
all_pars(2:numpars:4)%location = 2
all_pars(3:numpars:4)%location = 3
all_pars(4:numpars:4)%location = 4


!get particles in each location 
do n = 1,numlocs
!  allocate(all_locs(n)%pars(count(all_pars(:)%location .ne. n)))
  all_locs(n)%pars = pack(all_pars, (all_pars(:)%location .ne. n)) 
enddo
end program
```

and it compiles without a hitch on my Mac with Intel Fortran 13.something.  Of course, since you've only posted a syntactically-slightly-incorrect part of your code I can't be sure that this tells you very much.

Since you don't show that your code uses `implicit none` your error might be down to the difference between `all_loc` and `all_locs` or some other similar issue.

Note, in passing, that with Fortran allocatable arrays you don't need to allocate `all_locs(n)%pars` prior to setting its value with the call to `pack`, the compiler will take care of that for you.  This, though, is not the source of your error.

Comment: thanks for the response. i did not intend to make an actual full program, simply to flesh out the problem code. thank you for doing so, but it does not work for me. i can compile the code as you have it, but it leaves each all_locs%pars array as undefined in my debugger, and indeed adding a write statement shows the variables as blank. i am on linux with ifort 12.1.3.293

Comment: ah, i got it working. there was something wrong with the way you specified the particle locations, and i do indeed need the allocate statement (perhaps you can elaborate on why i should not need it?). as far as i can tell, my error was in the locations type definition, but i fixed it when i resketched my problem. i had "type (par), allocatable :: pars(:)" rather than the dimension(:) specified above.

Comment: @walrus You need the -assume realloc_lhs (which is included in the options enabled by -standard-semantics) command line option to enable automatic reallocation of the left hand side of an assignment in ifort.