# weird error the result of linking: "An assignment of different structure types is invalid."

Tags: fortran

I required some help with a question the other day, and fleshed out a very simplified example here: [fortran "array of arrays" and "pack" issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304409/fortran-array-of-arrays-and-pack-issues/17304843?noredirect=1#comment25103598_17304843) . This novel example was eventually made to work, but it did not solve the issues with my larger program. In an effort to further understand the error I am getting, I expanded the novel program to more accurately mimic the structure of my larger program. It turns out this indeed reproduces my error. Here are the code pieces I used:

test.f90

```
program main

use locs, only: alloc_locs,all_locs
implicit none
INCLUDE 'test.h'
integer :: numpars, numlocs, n

type (par), allocatable, dimension(:) :: all_pars

CALL alloc_locs

!read numpars, numlocs from file etc
numpars = 10

allocate(all_pars(numpars))

!initialize all_pars
all_pars(1:4)%location = 1
all_pars(5:6)%location = 2
all_pars(7:8)%location = 3
all_pars(9:10)%location = 4


!get particles in each location 
do n = 1,numlocs
  all_locs(n)%pars = pack(all_pars, (all_pars(:)%location .eq. n)) 
enddo

write(*,*) all_locs(2)%pars(1)%location
end program
```

test.h

```
type par
  !data
  integer :: location
end type par

type locations
  ! data
  type (par), allocatable, dimension(:) :: pars
end type locations
```

locs.f90

```
MODULE LOCS

IMPLICIT NONE
PUBLIC
SAVE

include 'test.h'
type (locations), allocatable, dimension(:) :: all_locs
CONTAINS
SUBROUTINE alloc_locs()

  integer :: numlocs

  numlocs = 4
  allocate(all_locs(numlocs))

END SUBROUTINE alloc_locs
END MODULE LOCS
```

makefile

```
FC = ifort

OBJS          = locs.o

FFLAGS =  -vec-report0 -O2 -fp-model precise -standard-semantics

test : $(OBJS)
    @echo "  Compiling"
    @$(FC) $(FFLAGS) -o test.exe test.f90 $(OBJS) 
    @\rm *.o *.mod
    @echo "  "
    @echo "  Compilation Successfully Completed"
    @echo "  "

%.o: %.f90
    @echo "  Compiling $<"
    @$(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $<

clean:
    \rm *.o *.mod test.exe
```

result of make:

```
Compiling locs.f90
Compiling
test.f90(27): error #6197: An assignment of different structure types is invalid.
  all_locs(n)%pars = pack(all_pars, (all_pars(:)%location .eq. n))
---------------------^
compilation aborted for test.f90 (code 1)
```

To me, this code and the code from the previous question are functionally the same, but obviously something is getting lost in translation that has to do with the module structure, or referring to test.h twice, and the structure somehow not being equivalent. I have found very little information about this error online, and none with any relevance to my issue as far as I can tell. Can someone explain what is going on to cause the issues, and how I may possibly go about sorting it? If the issue is the latter, how does one go about propagating a user defined type between modules?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your use of `include 'test.h'` is probably at the root of your problem ...

As you have written the code you declare types `par` and `locations` in two different scopes, once inside the program, once inside the module.  These derived types are different types despite their having the same name.  The fact that you have not use-associated them from the module to the program does not affect that.  So your variable `all_pars` inside the program has type `program::par` (as it were). The call inside the program to `alloc_locs` leads to `all_locs` having type `module::locations` and each instance of that type has a component of type `module::par`. So in this statement

```
all_locs(n)%pars = pack(all_pars, (all_pars(:)%location .eq. n))
```

on the *lhs* the pars are of type `module::par` and on the *rhs* the pars are of type `program::par`.

Or something like that, but to be honest I find your code exceedingly convoluted.  I do not understand why you want to define `par` and `locations` twice, why you do not simply declare them inside the module and use-associate them.

You ask *how does one go about propagating a user defined type between modules?*  The answer is that you define it in one module and use it from other modules or from the program itself.

Comment: Thanks v.much, I understand why it is happening now, but I am still no closer to fixing it. I dont want to (I really can't) instantiate everything in one module for my purposes. The larger code of course is a much more complex program. some variables need to be global in the main, and some need to be read in later and instantiated via another module. It just so happens, that one of these is a user defined type, and they need to interact with one another. So I am asking, how do I propagate a type definition from one module to another, in a manner that would make them equivalent? Is it possible?

Comment: Nevermind, I am apparently dense. I neglected to realize I could call USE at the top of the main to get the type defs via a module that has not otherwise been run yet. Thanks very much for your answers to both of my questions.